# extend HttpContext.User.Identity in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

in my application i want to use the current logged in user details, 
in HttpContext.User.Identity there are 'AuthenticationType', 'IsAuthenticated' and 'Name', I want some more details from database when user logged in to the system. Is there any way to extend this identity class?

Comment: You can make your own implementation of IPrincipal

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel noted in his comment you're going to need to create your own implementation of IPrincipal. I'm going to assume that you're using MVC5. If so, then you're going to need to implement an [authentication filter](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=957) which will allow you to set the principal for the request. This authentication filter would go to the database, retrieve the fields you have added, and populate your IPrincipal implementation. Finally, you would need to globally register that filter in your FilterConfig.cs file in App_Start so that it will be applied to every controller action in the application without you having to type it over and over again.